# AS3 pass MovieClip to super

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, super

I have a **Spaceship** `movieclip`, with a `movieclip` **Turret** inside.

`Spaceship extends` the `Unit class`, where I want to rotate the Turret.

In my `Spaceship constructor`, I use `super(this.turret);` but this always returns `null`.

Passing other variables works, and before calling `super()`, I can successfully trace `this.turret`

**So why can't I pass it to super? And how can I fix this?**

[edit]
Perhaps it has something to do with the turret not being available/added to stage yet when super() is called? If so, how could I deal with that and get it "Unit" anyways?

Comment: What is the class type of the argument in Unit's constructor?

Comment: I tried Object and MovieClip but both return null.

Comment: Please show us all related parts of Spaceship and Unit classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass `turret` into the `constructor` you are only passing a reference to the `MovieClip` with that instance name. What does the `Unit constructor` do with the parameter? I guess that your `Unit` class are not supposed to have a turret variable.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
public class SpaceShip extends Unit
{

    public var turret : MovieClip;

    public function SpaceShip()
    {
        super();
    }

}
```

---

```
// Access from other class where ship has been referenced
public class Test extends Sprite
{

    public var ship : SpaceShip;

    public function ship()
    {
        // access the public variable (reference) turrent
        ship.turrent.rotation += 25;
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually the constructor doesn't do anything with it, I just want it available for later use in the aim() function (in Unit.as).

Comment: Then you need to store the reference in a variable.

Comment: I want to do this rotation in the Unit class, because all Units will have the same aim method.

It's worth noting that the turret is not created by code, I just gave it a name on the timeline.

At the moment I got it to work by passing the turret to Unit not in the constructor, but with a setter, and only after an AddedToStage event.

It works, but it feels a little clumsy.

Comment: You could add a function called `aim` in the Unit class. Then override that funcion in the SpaceShip class and do the turret specific logic there.